Creating alert in kibana with Checking String pattern contains
Hi I want to check specific string set exist in my kibana logs and if it exist then I want to create alert
For Example My Pattern Hello World
and Request is Welcome to Hello World then trigger me alert
and Request is like Welcome to World then not trigger an alert

How can I due it in kibana rule part

Bilgehan selam, you should use match_phrase query to match with "Hello World" but not "World".
To use rules or watcher you should have a subscription.
Do you have an elastic license or is your elasticsearch hosted in elastic cloud?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html


Also, Is there any timestamp in your documents?


Also in the kibana screens should we put our string inside the double quotes "Hello World" or directly write Hello World

you should use match_phrase query to match with "Hello World" but not "World".
You can get alerts with rules or watcher. To use rules or watcher you should have a subscription. Do you have an elastic license or is your elasticsearch hosted in elastic cloud?
If you search Hello World in discover it will be a multi_match query and a document include hello or world will match. But if you search "Hello World" only the document with exactly have hello world will match because it will use type: phrase
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase

Watcher section in Kibana.

create a new Watcher rule.
2 "Actions"  - Select the action type you want (e.g., email, Slack, etc.).
"Conditions" - Define the condition to check if the specific string pattern exists in your logs.
You can use a query to match the logs containing the pattern.
json

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "your_field": "Hello World"
    }
  }
}

Review and save your Watcher rule.
